iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.4.99
I have been getting this error in my react native project since I upgraded Xcode from 14 to 15. I tried to the this in the Podfile:
platform :ios, '13.0'

And I tried this in the Podfile:
post_install do |installer|
    installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
        project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
            end
        end
    end
end


What does it say after the error/warning like (in target '' from project '')?

found any solution??

Had the same issue with flutter 3.24.3, because the project was created using an older version flutter. just delete the ios folder and create new files using
 flutter create  --platforms ios

don't forget to add any existing config such as google services etc
